# How Atom Editor Browser run ES6 Jasmine Tests

Tags: javascript, jasmine, ecmascript-6, atom-editor

I'm using Atom editor, and it runs javascript test with Jasmine for ES6, with functionalities that are not read by any browser so far.

I'm trying to find out how it is done. I need to run the tests outside Atom. I will read Atom source code in order to find out, but maybe some one already know that?

Another alternative I was thinking was to use Babel to translate to ES5 and then run the tests, but Atom way seems better.

Any ideas?